# IHttpActionResult WEB API Response Header

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I am using the `IHttpActionResult` Type for the API Call which is `Get` call and i want to send the Response Header in a same call above is my code

```
[HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSyncData()
    {
        syncDataRepository.Location = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SyncDataOfMobileDatatSet.Location);
        syncDataRepository.UserLocation = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SyncDataOfMobileDatatSet.UserLocation);
        syncDataRepository.UserAuthentication = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SyncDataOfMobileDatatSet.UserAuthentication);
        syncDataRepository.UserDetails = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SyncDataOfMobileDatatSet.UserDetails);
        syncDataRepository.TourOrganization = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SyncDataOfMobileDatatSet.TourOrganization);
        syncDataRepository.TourBatch = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SyncDataOfMobileDatatSet.TourBatch);
        syncDataRepository.TourSuperBatch = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SyncDataOfMobileDatatSet.TourSuperBatch);
        syncDataRepository.TourPlanItemChat = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SyncDataOfMobileDatatSet.TourPlanItemChat);
        syncDataRepository.TourBatchPlan = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SyncDataOfMobileDatatSet.TourBatchPlan);
        syncDataRepository.MyRole = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Roles.GetRolesForUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name));
        syncDataRepository.DeletedBatchPlan = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SyncDataOfMobileDatatSet.DeletedBatchPlan);
        syncDataRepository.Mode = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SyncDataOfMobileDatatSet.Mode);
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(syncDataRepository);

        return Json(syncDataRepository);
    }
```

i tried with `HttpContext.Response` but i am getting it as null. so is there any other way please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: Sorry, its not clear what you would like to do. Do you want to set some response headers? If so, which ones, and to what value?

Comment: yes i want to send response header which will contain one datetime value.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a response header by implementing the IHttpActionResult and setting the header in the ExecuteAsync method like so :

```
public class DateHeaderActionResult<TContent> : IHttpActionResult
{
  private DateTime _date;
  private TContent _content;
  private HttpRequestMessage _request;

  public DateHeaderActionResult(DateTime date, TContent content, HttpRequestMessage request)
  {
    _date = date;
    _content = content;
    _request = request;
  }

  public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Headers.Add("MyDate", _date.ToString("yyyyMMddThhmmss"));
    response.Content = new ObjectContent<TContent>(_content, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    return Task.FromResult(response);
  }
}
```

And then in your controller instead of returning

```
return Json(syncDataRepository);
```

You would return

```
return new DateHeaderActionResult<SyncDataRepository>(DateTime.Now, syncDataRepository, Request);
```

That's assuming the syncDataRepository class name is SyncDataRepository